# Retention policy in SharePoint 2013 on premise

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, central-administration, sharepoint-library, retention

This is a question from **SharePoint 2013 administrators** who are already working with retention policy. 
I suppose to make a **Shared Library** with high capacity for my users so they can transfer their **heavy contents**including Images, films &...
I heard from an SP adviser that **"retention policy will cause heavy loading the server, even it's working on a library it will review the whole server."**
So what is the best way to do so? The idea is like a **We transfer** or a **user share**. I would appreciate to here your experiences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, the only heavy load on the server is the initial implementation of the policies and expiration. The first run can go on for a while if you have a lot of files to remove.

There are 2 timer jobs that run this process, the first marks documents for expiration that meet retention policies and the other comes through and cleans them up. The default value of these is to run weekly and in typical off hours fashion.

Since they are timer jobs, you can adjust the frequency they run and when they run to reduce impact.

Comment: Thanks for your short and rich answer. Just one more question is that what is your opinion about the idea itself? would you do so for such case? if you didn't what is your suggestion?

Comment: Overall it is fine on a library by library basis. If it is something you want to do across the entirety of the farm, it can be difficult to manage. Also something to consider is if people are storing records in SharePoint, you want to use this carefully to not destroy business records that are not expired yet. Careful planning and a tight information architecture is helpful.

Comment: Thanks... "Careful planning and a tight information architecture" was sth marginal for me, I was sticking to the technical part.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in many cases it cause the heavy load on the servers. Properly planning required to configure this.

**Policy update**

> Policy update is a long-running operation that is handled by a timer
>   job. Policy update occurs when a policy change, such as adding a
>   retention action, is made to a content type. The performance of policy
>   updates is affected by the number of content databases, the
>   capabilities of the hardware that is running SQL Server, and the site
>   template the item is in. To update items faster, you can split content
>   across multiple site collections with separate content databases.
>
> > In large-scale document repositories a large number of items might

**Retention**

> have policy and retention actions configured. Retention actions are
>   long-running operations because a large number of items might need to
>   be processed and have the appropriate retention action applied. In
>   cases where a large amount of content will expire, the rate of
>   processing might be a limitation. Proper planning must be done for the
>   rate of expiration.

Retention policy depend upon on the two Timer Jobs ( Information management policy & Expiration policy). You can schdule these jobs run over the weekend or off hours so that put less load on the server. as you mentioned, you have a document library for heavy usages then you should perform a load test on a lower environment to make sure things are in control.

Read this article, will help you [Estimate performance and capacity requirements for large scale document repositories in SharePoint Server 2010](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh395916%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thank you for complete information. The 2 timer job was new. I would appreciate to hear your experience regarding the idea of Doc transferring.